# How to "HTML encode" Em Dash in Visual Basic.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, encoding

I am generating some text to be shown on a web-site, and use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) to ensure it will look correct. However, this method does not appear to encode the [Em Dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdash#Em_dash) (it should convert it to "—").

I have come up with a solution, but I'm sure there is a better way of doing it - some library function or something.

```
sWebsiteText = _
    "<![CDATA[" & _
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sSomeText) & _
    "]]>"

'This is the bit which seems "hacky"'
sWebsiteText = _
    sWebsiteText.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#8211;"), "&#8211;")
```

So my question is - how would you implement the "hacky" part?

Many thanks,

RB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bobince's answer gives a solution to what seems to be your main concern : replacing your use of HtmlDecode by a more straightforward declaration of the char to replace.
Rewrite

```
sWebsiteText.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#8211;"), "&#8211;")
```

as

```
sWebsiteText.Replace("\u2013", "&#x2013;")
```

('\u2014' (dec 8212) is em dash, '\u2013' (dec 8211) is en dash.)
For readability purpose it may be considered better to use "&#x2013;" rather than "&#8211;", since the .Net declaration for the char ("\u2013") is in hex too. But, as decimal notation seems more common in html, I personaly would prefer using "&#8211;".
For reuse purpose, you probably should write your own HtmlEncode function declared in a custom HttpUtility, in order to be able to call it from anywhere else in your site without duplicating it.
(Have something like (sorry I have written it in C#, forgetting your examples were in VB):

```
/// <summary>
/// Supplies some custom processing to some HttpUtility functions.
/// </summary>
public static class CustomHttpUtility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Html encodes a string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">string to be encoded.</param>
    /// <returns>A html encoded string.</returns>
    public static string HtmlEncode(string input)
    {
        if (intput == null)
            return null;
        StringBuilder encodedString = new StringBuilder(
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input));
        encodedString.Replace("\u2013", "&#x2013;");
        // add over missing replacements here, as for &#8212;
        encodedString.Replace("\u2014", "&#x2014;");
        //...

        return encodedString.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then replace

```
sWebsiteText = _
    "<![CDATA[" & _
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sSomeText) & _
    "]]>"
'This is the bit which seems "hacky"'
sWebsiteText = _
    sWebsiteText.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#8211;"), "&#8211;")
```

With:

```
sWebsiteText = _
    "<![CDATA[" & _
    CustomHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sSomeText) & _
    "]]>"
```

)

Answer (score 3):

> As this character is not an ASCII character, how do I encode it?

It's not an ASCII character, but it is a Unicode character, U+2014. If your page output is going to be UTF-8, which in this day and age it really should be, you don't need to HTML-encode it, just output the character directly.

> Are there other characters which are likely to give me problems.

What problems exactly is it giving you? If you can't output '—', you probably can't output any other non-ASCII Unicode character, which is thousands of them.

Replace "\u2014" with "& #x2014;" if you really must, but really with today's Unicode-aware tools there should be no need to go around replacing every non-ASCII Unicode character with markup.

Comment: I've updated my question with my current solution - I think that might explain my problem better than I have been.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is trying to do. You don't need a CDATA section, HTML encoding doesn't work inside a CDATA section, and neither HtmlEncode nor HtmlDecode do anything special with Unicode characters. Don't do any of this, just use UTF-8 and spit the HtmlEncoded output directly into the page.

Comment: Oh - sorry. I should have explained that. It's a web-feed to a property portal (in this case, www.fish4.co.uk), so it is web-content, delivered in an XML element, hence the CDATA tags.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/emen), as I suggested in [HTML Apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419718/html-apostrophe) question.

The em dash — is represented by `&#8212;`.

Comment: I should have been clearer - my problem is not finding what to encode it to, it's finding what to encode it from. I'll fix the question to make that clear.