# how to encode apostrophes for a webpage

Tags: c#, jquery, html, apostrophe, cluetip

i am using [the cluetip plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/) and the simple use case is to to put the content in a title attribute, like below:

```
<a title='Top title|detail content'>Text</a>
```

i am now running into issues where the string that is inside "detail content' has an apostrophe inside of it and it seems to confuse cluetip plugin. Is there anyway to escape or encode an apostrophe to allow cluetip to work properly.

Comment: In .net 4.0 System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode works, but in 3.5 for some reason it skips single apostrophes.  You can use System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape if you're in 3.5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for `&apos;`.
See [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: is there an method in the .net 3.5 library to take a string and convert all of these characters like apostrophe and convert them to their equivalent (&apos; in this case)

Comment: htmlEncode method doesn't seem to do anything to apostrophes.

Comment: @ooo: Sorry; `HtmlAttributeEncode`.  (But you also need to use double-quoted attributes)

Comment: reasons for using System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape given @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/1934252/41153

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `&#39;` per [this link](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html) since `&apos;` has flaky browser support.  See [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419718/html-apostrophe) for more info.

Comment: &#39; is single quote. &#8217; is apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried HTML escaping the apostrophe?