# Crystal Reports HTML formatting

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having some issues with special characters in Crystal Reports. I have some data that has come in and out of SQL via XML so some of the charters have been converted to special characters.

For instance & are converted to `&amp;` and ' are converted to `&apos`. When the data is represented in Crystal Reports with text interpretation set to HTML it shows the `&amp;` as & like it should. The problem I am having is that `&apos` is not being converted to ' it just stays as `&apos`.

Does anyone have any idea why it would not convert `&apos` to '?

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Crystal Reports returning `&apos` or `&apos;`? If the semicolon is missing that could be the problem.

Comment: I just typed it wrong here. It's &apos;. Other systems are displaying it right but for some reason Crystal is not converting it.

Comment: I've noticed that you've been a member for 6 months and have yet to mark an answer as the correct answer or cast a vote. Please understand that many users look at this to decide whether a question is worth attempting to answer, so you may not continue to receive quality answers without participating in this civic responsibility. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `&apos;` is an XML character entity reference where `&#39;` or even `&#8217;` are for html. I would have hoped the Crystal Reports html conversion might have supported xml characters too, but I guess not. Note that it appears as though `&apos;` does not work IE. I hope this helps.

See the following links for more details:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML (1st result in search for "apos" on the page)

[HTML code for an apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419718/html-apostrophe)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp