# Trying to Wrap my brain around HTML character encodings and htmlspecialchars()

Tags: html, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I've been trying to get a proper understanding of character-encoding in HTML, and was hoping someone might be able to help me out with a small problem I've been encountering.

I'm pulling a paragraph of text from a mySQL database table (latin-1).  The paragraph happens to have a right-single-quote in it, and I read it was a good idea to run that sort of string data through `htmlspecialchars()` before displaying on the screen, so I tried...

```
// So let's say $paragraph is a string like "The customer's computer is on".

echo htmlspecialchars($paragraph);
```

This renders to the screen as `"The customer'&#8217;s computer is on"`. At first I thought that was weird, because I expected the `&#8217;` to automatically be rendered as a right-single-quote, but then I thought maybe I'd forgotten the meta-tag.  Since the database table was latin-1, I thought the following tag would help it render correctly...

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

But still no dice, it's still showing up as `&#8217;`.  I also tried...

```
htmlspecialchars($paragraph, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

But it's still rendering the same.  If I don't even use `htmlspecialchars()` it renders to the screen as expected, but I guess I'm just trying to understand why `htmlspecialchars()` doesn't render the way I was expecting.  Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding the functions and how they're supposed to be rendering in the browser, so any help on this would be really appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**:  To add some more oddness to the equation, I tried manually typing in `&#8217;` into the HTML document, and it does in fact render as right single-quotes.  However, when I look at the HTML I see `&#8217;` where the htmlspecialchars() is outputting, instead of the right single-quote I was expecting.  Does anyone know why that might be?  Is that expected functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this post:
[HTML code for an apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419718/html-apostrophe)

The apostrophe and the right single quote are two different characters. Perhaps it is rendering correctly because the apostrophe is what is in the db?

Comment: Is that what htmlspecialchars is supposed to do though?  I guess I thought when it places the html-entity into the document, I thought the browser would process it and display it as an actual right-single-quote on the screen.  Is that line of thinking incorrect?  Is it really supposed to just render as the unicode text?