# Ignore the special characters from the string

Tags: java, liferay, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

I am having a string which contains some special characters. ie "MCDO'S ".
here in the code i am replacing it with the ascii html values like this.

```
riDescription.replace("\"", "").replace("\\", "").replace("'", "&#39;");
```

here `'` is replaced by `&#39;`
Now the result which i am getting in UI is like this.

[image: the string is appearing with the html values]

Comment: In action class, you can use, `HtmlUtil.escape` (for storing in DB) to replace these special characters with respective ASCII literals. While on UI `HtmlUtil.unescape` will do the trick.

Comment: I believe you will get your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620543/java-how-to-encode-single-quote-and-double-quote-into-html-entities

Comment: @ParkashKumar i ve passed this string in HtmlUtil.escape and in jsp again i am trying to unescape it but no success.

Comment: Have you verified by printing both values? Do you observe any difference?

Comment: @ParkashKumar in console only i am getting this 08:31:04,830 INFO  [OpsController:382] MCDO&#x27;S NALS FLAG&#x27;

Answer (score 0):

Description.replace("\"", "").replace("'", "'");

Comment: Sorry this is the same i am trying to do but no help